# Undefined method `error_span' - Rails Project

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, runtime-error

I am creating a job portal application in Rails 4.1 using Ruby 1.9

The application initially was running fine, but unexpectedly an error popped up. The jobs subdirectory in the views directory contains two files new.html.erb and _form.html.erb(this is a partial file). While rendering the new file, the partial file is also rendered from the new file.

But, the application is showing the following error in Rubymine

**ERROR DETAILS:**
"NoMethodError in Jobs#new"

Showing E:/RailsProject/Old/FinalSubm/jobportal/app/views/jobs/_form.html.erb where line #23 raised:

undefined method `error_span' at line 23

```
   20    <div class="controls">
   21      <%= f.text_field :title, :class => 'form-control' %>
   22    </div>
   23    <%= error_span(@job[:title]) %>
   24  </div>
   25  <div class="control-group">
   26    <%= f.label :description, :class => 'control-label' %>
```

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/jobs/new.html.erb

Rails.root: E:/RailsProject/Old/FinalSubm/jobportal

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/jobs/_form.html.erb:23:in `block in _app_views_jobs__form_html_erb__604570268_42022236'

app/views/jobs/_form.html.erb:1:in`_app_views_jobs__form_html_erb__604570268_42022236' app/views/jobs/new.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_jobs_new_html_erb___144564004_42034104'

**The following is the code written for E:/RailsProject/Old/FinalSubm/jobportal/app/views/jobs/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @job, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal job" } do |f| %>

    <% if @job.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_expl" class="panel panel-danger">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><%= pluralize(@job.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this job from being saved:</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
        <% @job.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :title, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :title, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <%= error_span(@job[:title]) %>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :description, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_area :description, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <%= error_span(@job[:description]) %>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :tag1, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%=  f.select :tag1, options_for_select(%w[Internship Full-Time Part-Time Co-Op Contractor]) %>
    </div>
    <%= error_span(@job[:tag1]) %>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :tag2, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.select :tag2, options_for_select(%w[Work-From-Home Office]) %>
    </div>
    <%= error_span(@job[:tag2]) %>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :tag3, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.select :tag3, options_for_select(%w[US-Citizen Non-US-Citizen]) %>
    </div>
    <%= error_span(@job[:tag3]) %>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :category, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.select :category_name, Category.all.collect{ |c| [c.name, c.id]} %>
    </div>
    <%= error_span(@job[:category_name]) %>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :deadline, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.date_select :deadline, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <%= error_span(@job[:deadline]) %>
  </div>
 <!-- <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :employer_id, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.number_field :employer_id, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <%= error_span(@job[:employer_id]) %>
  </div>
   <%= f.hidden_field :employer_id  %>
  <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
            jobs_path, :class => 'btn btn-default' %>

<% end %>
```

**The following is the code written for E:/RailsProject/Old/FinalSubm/jobportal/app/views/jobs/new.html.erb**

```
<%- model_class = Job -%>
<div class="page-header">
  <h1><%=t '.title', :default => [:'helpers.titles.new', 'New %{model}'], :model => model_class.model_name.human.titleize %></h1>
</div>
<%= render :partial => 'form' %>
```

The program was running fine a couple of days back, no changes have been made to the code since then, apart from restarting the rails server. I am trying to figure out where this error popped from. To solve this error should I define the method error_span in Jobs#new controller ?. What should be written in it ? OR Should I remove the error_span statement from the views, but this would imply that many changes would have to be made in the code, since I have 8 to 10 more files where the partial file mentioning the html statement needs to be changed.

Comment: I will not believe that the problem suddenly appeared and nothing has changed. That would mean your machine is developing a brain. Are you running it on the very same machine as before? Have you installed any new gems, run `bundle update` or anything like this? Where is `error_span` method defined? Also, do you have any form of source control to check what has changed since last time it did work?

Comment: I am using github as VCS, and this time I tried by running the cloned repository, still the problem persists. However, I deleted the error_span statement from the code and now the code runs fine. To answer your above question, the error_span method is defined nowhere, hence it was throwing error. I have no idea where to define the error_span method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using `twitter-bootstrap-rails` (which is where I'm guessing the `error_span` method comes from).

Try using the latest code by putting in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git', :branch => 'master'
```

Because it looks like they fixed this method a few weeks ago.

more info:https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/pull/795

Comment: Yes, I am using **twitter-bootstrap-rails**. I have modified the gem file, shutdown the server, ran **bundle update** , and then started the server again, but still the same error persists "No method defined 'error_span' "

Answer (score 3):

`twitter-bootstrap-rails`has a bug in lib/generators/bootstrap/themed/templates/

```
 <%%= error_span(@<%= resource_name %>[:<%= column.name %>]) %>
```

change to

```
  <%%= f.error_span(:<%= column.name %>) %>
```

.erb && slim templete has the same bug.
[here is a fixed version](https://github.com/qx/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git)

Comment: twitter-bootstrap-rails 3.2.2 has this bug, as described.

Comment: This fixed it for me.
`error_span(@post[:content])` changed to `f.error_span(:content)`

Answer (score 1):

Based on @NoelProf's answer, I changed my Gemfile:

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', '>= 3.2.0', '< 3.2.2'
```

This will not install the version 3.2.2.

I restarted the server and the `error_span` problem has been gone.

Comment: Remember to restart server after installing the `twitter-bootstrap-rails` gem.